# Random Polynom Plot

Tags: functions

I should write a module "RandomPolyPlot[n, amin, amax]" which calculates all roots  (nulls) of a n-th degree polynomial function.

Then I should illustrate it on the complex plane. I also should illustrate a unit circle on that complex plane. The coefficients a0, a1 ... an should be real random numbers in the range {amin, amax}. At the end I should test the function with the following: `RandomPolyPlot[10,0,1] und RandomPolyPlot[100,-1,1]`

Can anybody help me please. Its my first function and I don't know what to do :(

Comment: Is this by some chance homework assignment?

Comment: I agree with @kirma that this sounds like a HW assignment, so I'll be intentionally vague here.  Generally, using a `Module` is best done in two steps:  first, write a piece of code that does what you want for some fixed values of the parameters;  then, wrap it in a `Module` command to make it into a function of those parameters.  Which aspect are you having trouble with?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Actually... search for "`RandomPolyPlot[10,0,1] und RandomPolyPlot[100,-1,1]`". This is an exercise assignment. Sadly I had to delete my otherwise nice answer because of this... (I also doubt my answer would have seemed a bit inauthentic for basic programming course answer.)

Comment: This is your third question here and you should heed the comments and start showing some effort instead of simply pasting assignments.

Comment: @kirma Damn! Take a look at my answer :) (I didn't see yours before)

Answer (score 1):

```
ranpolyplot[a_, n_] := Module[{roots, RI, f, x},
f[x_] = Sum[a[[i]] x^(i - 1), {i, n}];
roots = x /. NSolve[f[x] == 0, x];
RI = Transpose[roots /. z_ -> {Re[z], Im[z]}];
ListPlot[RI, PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, {-1.5, 1.5}},
   AspectRatio -> 1, AxesLabel -> {Re, Im}]]]
```

Now you have to feed it the coefficients and order of polynomial.

```
coeff = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 100];
ranpolyplot[coeff, 100]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
ranpolyplot[n_, r_] := Module[{x}, 
  ListPlot[{Re@#, Im@#} & /@ (x /. NSolve[FromDigits[RandomReal[r, n + 1], x]]), 
           AspectRatio -> 1]]

ranpolyplot[100, {1, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]